# Is there any need to ensure correct data type is submitted to MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

After writing a PHP function to ensure data parsed from a csv is inputed as its correct format (to match the column data type set when creating the table), I've learned that MySQL by default will output all values as strings anyway.

My question is therefore - is there any need to ensure an integer (for an id column that has been set to store integers only) IS an integer and not a string containing a number ( "1" for example) before inserting into MySQL database?

If not, then what is the thinking behind explicitly stating what values a column should store when creating tables in MySQL?

Comment: For the purposes of this, define "integer". It's harder than you might think. Also everything in a CSV file is a string wether you like it or not.

Comment: insert into a string `1` into an int column will work as expected. but that may not always be the case. e.g. inserting a string date in a format other than what mysql expects, into a date field, will almost always end up badly. mysql REQUIRES dates to be `yyyy-mm-dd`. if you insert something like `dd-yyyy-mm`, you're going to end up with corrupted data.

Comment: the proper method of escaping is dependent on the type

Comment: Reasoning behind types is the storage requirement and what you do with the data. Consider integer `123456` and string `"123456"` - to us humans, both have 6 digits / characters. However, to store a character you would need 1 byte, for each of the "digits" in the string. But, to store the number `123456` you would need only 3 bytes - this is a very, very crude example about storage requirements, we could write a whole book about it but the basic premise is that you don't waste space and RAM if you can be smart about what you save.

Comment: If you have already verified the data type of the data upon input from CSV, there is not need to re-verify it before inserting it into the database assuming it hasn't been further altered (especially via user input) in the interim.  If you used parametrized prepared statements to do the DB inputs (you are using prepared statements aren't you?),  then you can specify the data type being bound in most MySQL libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are being converted between string and integer.  When inserting a row into MySQL both PHP and MySQL can convert a string of "1" into an integer 1.  Try passing a string "notanumber" into an Integer field, it's not going to work because you can't convert that string value into a number.  The reason MySQL returns strings in selecting is so everything is in one type of format, there may be another reason for it - but it's easier to know everything in your results is a string and not have to check if it's an integer, or a float, or whatever else.  With PHP and implicit conversion this isn't a huge deal, but for a language like C# that is very strongly typed this can save a lot of time.  You know it's a string, and convert to what you want if need be instead of checking for tons of different possibilities.

You definitely should be checking data before inserting, or at least handling the MySQL errors if you don't.  You can check using `isset($var)` for null or empty values, `is_numeric($var)` for integers, `is_float($var)` for floats.  I would recommend validating everything before putting it into the database.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of data types will be automaticly cast towards the correct type in MySQL. I.e. inserting a number to a varchar field will become a string.

The thinking about stating the column types have several reason, mostly for speed and space optimization. Off course you can create all fields as varchars, but storing the number 300000000 in a varchar field would need (at least) 9 bytes while for an integer field a basic 32bit (4 bytes) would be enough. Comparing integer numbers (in the where clause)  is easy, but numbers in strings is different. I.e. ordering string cat,cars,car will be: car, cars, cat. But how would you order strings 1000,1200 and 10000? As strings it would be 1000, 10000, 1200. As numbers 1000,1200 and 10000.

Answer (score 1):

For ints/strings, data types aren't too critical while inserting. You can probably find some edge cases where an exotic floating point value-as-string doesn't insert properly. MySQL for the most part will do the right thing when forced to do type juggling while inserting. A string inserted into a numeric-type field will get converted to a number, as best as MySQL can.

The major problem is when it comes time to actually USE the data you've inserted. That's when number v.s. string distinctions become critical:

```
mysql> create table test (strings varchar(2), integers int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values ('12', 12), ('2', 2), ('112', 112);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test;
+---------+----------+
| strings | integers |
+---------+----------+
| 12      |       12 |
| 2       |        2 |
| 112     |      112 |
+---------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Simple select, sorting via the integer field:

```
mysql> select * from test order by integers;
+---------+----------+
| strings | integers |
+---------+----------+
| 2       |        2 |
| 12      |       12 |
| 112     |      112 |
+---------+----------+
```

Everything ok with integer sorting. We get nicely sorted ascending list.

But when it comes time for the strings:

```
mysql> select * from test order by strings asc;
+---------+----------+
| strings | integers |
+---------+----------+
| 112     |      112 |
| 12      |       12 |
| 2       |        2 |
+---------+----------+
```

Ooops... totally wrong. MySQL (properly) sorted as strings, and by string rules, `112` is smaller than `2`.